# Monte Carlo Search Tree iterations

Tags: algorithms, trees, monte-carlo, algorithmic-game-theory

I have had this example in my exam last week and I can not figure out how to solve it. I have watched lots of tutorials on Monte Carlo Search Tree but I can't still understand this algorithm properly.

I know the four phases: *selection, expansion, simulation, backpropagation.*

Can someone please explain me the task b) in the image below? It would be really helpful.

[Monte Carlo Search Tree iterations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y4Fw.png)